# How do I make a relative path for header files in QMAKE

Tags: qt, qt-creator, relative-path, qmake

I am able to use the `QMAKE_POST_LINK = copy address\goes\here.h and\pastes\here.h` but want to take the original address as a relative path. I tried something like this…

```
HEADERS += -L”$$PWD/header.h” -header.h 

QMAKE_POST_LINK = copy -H”$$PWD\header.h” -header.h C:\really\long\address\goes\here\header.h;
```

this didn’t work, so I tried something like this from a library relative path example I found earlier like so…

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK = copy -L”..\header.h” -header.h C:\really\long\address\goes\here\header.h;
```

Does anyone know how to copy a header file using a relative path approach? Or is it simply impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago i implement a shared precompiled header, i used the following approach to copy a .pdb file to a other directory:

In .qmake.conf:

```
root_dir = $$PWD
```

In .pro File:

```
QMAKE_PRE_BUILD += xcopy /D /Y "$$root_dir\\src\\precompilemfc\\debug\\vc100.pdb" "$(ProjectDir)\\debug" &
```

Look [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#pwd). PWD or _PRO_FILE_PWD_ are the correct way to do what you want.

In qt do not use "\", use "\\" or better "/" instead.

This should work:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK = copy "$$PWD\\header.h" C:\\really\\long\\address\\goes\\here;
```

Comment: Still no luck. I am now using "\\" and I attempted to use QMAKE_POST_LINK = copy "$$PWD\\header.h" C:\\really\\long\\address\\goes\\here;

Comment: Which qt version do you use?

Comment: I am using version 5.3.1

Comment: What do you mean with "it didnt" work? $$PWD is empty?